# Rubik's cube with different neighboring color

Tags: rubiks-cube

How many valid configuration of the 3x3x3 Rubik's cube are there so that no two adjacent faces are the same color?

Thanks.

Comment: Does 'valid configuration' mean the solved 3x3x3 cube ? or are you just asking about a simple cube?

Comment: Yes. Any configuration that can be reached from a solved cube is considered a valid configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Computing this exactly seems *extremely* challenging.

I wrote some Rust code (below) to scramble a cube 10 million times and test whether two adjacent stickers are the same color. On my machine, it took a few minutes to run and produced the number 56. Multiplying this by 43 quintillion total states, empiricrally there are around **241 trillion** such states. This is far too many to brute-force search without some very powerful pruning.

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

use cubesim::{prelude::*, FaceletCube};
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;
use rayon::prelude::*;

const PRINT_EVERY: usize = 100_000;
const ITERATIONS: usize = 10_000_000;
const BATCH_SIZE: usize = 1000;

const SCRAMBLE_LENGTH: usize = 30;

#[derive(Debug, Default, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Stats {
    completed: usize,
    next_print: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let all_moves = cubesim::all_moves(3);

    let stats = Mutex::new(Stats::default());

    let spooky_states: usize = (0..ITERATIONS / BATCH_SIZE)
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|_| {
            let mut ret = 0;

            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

            for _ in 0..BATCH_SIZE {
                let mut cube = FaceletCube::new(3);

                for _ in 0..SCRAMBLE_LENGTH {
                    cube = cube.apply_move(*all_moves.choose(&mut rng).unwrap());
                }

                if is_spooky(&cube) {
                    ret += 1;
                }
            }

            let mut stats = stats.lock().unwrap();
            stats.completed += BATCH_SIZE;
            while stats.completed >= stats.next_print {
                println!("Completed {}", stats.next_print);
                stats.next_print += PRINT_EVERY;
            }

            ret
        })
        .sum();

    println!("{spooky_states} states out of {ITERATIONS} are spooky.")
}

fn is_spooky(cube: &FaceletCube) -> bool {
    !cube.state().chunks(9).any(|face| {
        face[0] == face[1]
            || face[1] == face[2]
            || face[3] == face[4]
            || face[4] == face[5]
            || face[6] == face[7]
            || face[7] == face[8]
            || face[0] == face[3]
            || face[3] == face[6]
            || face[1] == face[4]
            || face[4] == face[7]
            || face[2] == face[5]
            || face[5] == face[8]
    })
}
```

Dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
cubesim = "0.0.7"
rand = "0.8.5"
rayon = "1.5.3"
```