# How many good position are there?

Tags: combinatorics, rubiks-cube

Two squares on a Rubik's Cube are adjacent if they share a side.

A "good" position of a cube is such that no two adjacent squares have the same color.

As I try, it's pretty tough to find a good position (Of course except L2 R2 U2 D2 F2 B2)

And my questions are:

1. How many good position of a Rubik's Cube are there?
2. There aren't any good position of a nxnxn cube. Does n exist? And if yes, what is the smallest value of n?

Comment: There are some more examples at https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/429/is-it-possible-to-scramble-a-rubiks-cube-such-that-no-two-squares-of-the-same-c also at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matthew_van_eerde/2008/05/16/unsolving-the-rubiks-cube/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rubik's cube with different neighboring color](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828639/rubiks-cube-with-different-neighboring-color)